# How to do left join in doctrine with entity manager?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a query in sql like that

```
select * from films F left join ballot_films  BF on F.FilmId=BF.FilmId where BF.FilmId is null;
```

i want to convert it into doctrine, i m new with doctrine and don't know so much, i searched and tried a lot but didn't get any success,please help me to how can i do that query in doctrine using entity managaer, million ton thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the correct mappings between **films** and **ballot_films**, the following should work:

```
// Get the entity manager
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager("em");

// Get your film repository
$filmRepository = $em->getRepository("Film");

// Create the initial query builder
$query = $filmRepository->createQueryBuilder("films");

// Set your query criteria
$query->select("films")
      ->leftJoin("ballot_films")
      ->where("ballot_films.FilmId = null");

// Get the query results
$films = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This will give you all **films** where **ballot_films.FilmId** is null.